# React Native conflict between states with the same name in different screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm a beginner in React Native, in two different screen I used the same state name, in "branchScreen.js" where "outcomes" state includes only a summary of them while in "outcomeScreen.js" includes the whole collection. Everything seems to work but when you "visit" branchScreen.js and then go to outcomeScreen.js this last one stop re-rendering on outcomes state change. I solved this by changing the name of the state in branchScreen for outcomesToday, **but I'd like to know why does that happen, just to understand React better.** Thanks!

branchScreen.js

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Pressable,
  RefreshControl,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getData } from "../api/api-connections";
import IncomeList from "../components/IncomeList";
import OutcomeList from "../components/OutcomeList";
import { API_HOST } from "../utils/constants";
import { globalStyles } from "../utils/globalStyles";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function BranchScreen(props) {
  const { auth, branch, logout } = useAuth();
  [incomesToday, setIncomesToday] = useState([]);
  [outcomesToday, setOutcomesToday] = useState(null);
  [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      (async () => {
        await loadItems().catch((error) => console.log(error));
      })();
    }, [branch])
  );

  const onRefresh = React.useCallback(async () => {
    await loadItems().catch((error) => console.log(error));
    setRefreshing(false);
  }, []);

  const loadItems = async () => {
    if (branch) {
      try {
        const response = await getData("/branches/" + branch, auth);
        setOutcomesToday(response.outcomes);
        setIncomesToday(response.incomes);
        setOrders(response.orders);
        setStatus(response.status);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };

  const { navigation } = props;

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={[globalStyles.content, { marginTop: 40 }]}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
      }
    >
      {branch ? (
        <>
          <Text style={globalStyles.title_1}>Ventas hoy</Text>
          <IncomeList incomes={incomes} />
          <Text style={globalStyles.title_1}>Gastos hoy</Text>
          <OutcomeList outcomes={outcomesToday} />
          <Pressable
            style={globalStyles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              console.log("ir a todos los datos");
            }}
          >
            <Text style={globalStyles.buttonText}>Ver todos los gastos</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </>
      ) : (
        <Text style={globalStyles.title_1}>No hay datos que mostrar</Text>
      )}
      <Pressable style={globalStyles.button} onPress={logout}>
        <Text style={globalStyles.buttonText}>Salir</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

this is outcomeBranches.js

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Pressable,
  RefreshControl,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import OutcomeList from "../components/OutcomeList";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { getData } from "../api/api-connections";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
import { globalStyles } from "../utils/globalStyles";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { colors } from "../utils/constants";

export default function OutcomeScreen() {
  const { auth, branch } = useAuth();
  [outcomes, setOutcomes] = useState(null);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const goTo = () => {
    navigation.navigate("createOutcome");
  };
  const loadItems = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await getData("/outcomes", auth);
      setOutcomes(response.outcomes);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      (async () => {
        await loadItems().catch((error) => console.log(error));
      })();
    }, [])
  );

  const onRefresh = React.useCallback(async () => {
    await loadItems().catch((error) => console.log(error));
    setRefreshing(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={[globalStyles.content, { marginTop: 40 }]}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
      }
    >
      <Pressable style={globalStyles.button} onPress={goTo}>
        <Text style={globalStyles.buttonText}>Crear Gasto</Text>
      </Pressable>
      {outcomes ? (
        <OutcomeList outcomes={outcomes} />
      ) : (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={styles.spinner} color="black" />
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: `[outcomes, setOutcomes] = useState(null);` The issue is that you need `const` at the start of this and all similar lines. Without `const` you're making global variables, and then the other component overwrites those.

Comment: thats!!!!! it mate!, thank you very much!, I totally dropped the ball there!